# How to change font sizes in PDFTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Is there a solution other than the one [listed here](http://www.physik.uzh.ch/~psaha/misc/tex/mag.php)?
Which I quote:

> Some current distributions of pdfTeX have a bug (feature?) that using
>   `\magnification` rescales the paper along with the printing. The results
>   can look very puzzling. This happens only with pdf output, not with
>   dvi.
>
> The reason is that the pdf dimensions relating to the paper size have
>   been set in pt instead of truept. The cure is simple enough: after
>   `\magnification` just insert something like this.
>
> ```
> \pdfpagewidth=210.2truemm  \pdfpageheight=297.3truemm
> % This is for A4 paper, use 8truein and 11truein for letter-size paper.
> \pdfhorigin=1truein \pdfvorigin=1truein
> \hsize=\pdfpagewidth  \advance\hsize by -2truein
> \vsize=\pdfpageheight \advance\vsize by -2.1truein
> ```
>
> There are some patches that will save you this trouble. Javier Bezos's
>   fix is included in TeX Live. Ian Hutchinson offers another solution
>   which is a small masterpiece of deviousness in itself. It needs to be
>   read in full to be appreciated, but here is a sample, one worthy of
>   any list of TeX Dirty Tricks.
>
> ```
> \begingroup
> \catcode`P=12 \catcode`T=12
> \lowercase{\endgroup\def\convert@truept#1PT{#1truept}}
> ```

Comment: Don't use `\magnification` with PDF.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Should one use `mag` of the geometry package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer a variant of `pdftexmagfix.tex` that doesn't leave useless macros behind itself:

```
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfoutput\endcsname\relax\else
\catcode`@=11
\def\m@g{%
  \begingroup\lccode`?=`p \lccode`!=`t
  \lowercase{\def\pdfconvert@truept##1?!{##1truept}%
  \def\pdfmag@fix##1{##1=\expandafter\pdfconvert@truept\the##1\relax}}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \mag\count@
    \pdfmag@fix\pdfhorigin   \pdfmag@fix\pdfvorigin
    \pdfmag@fix\pdfpagewidth \pdfmag@fix\pdfpageheight}\x
  \hsize6.5truein\vsize8.9truein\dimen\footins8truein}
\catcode`@=12
\fi

%%% The test
\magnification \magstep5
\hoffset -1 truein  \voffset -1 truein
\parindent 0pt  The top
\bye
```